# what is state management in asp.net

Tags: asp.net

hi all i want to know that we can store information and session information of a user as well as control in three approch

1. View State
2. session state
3. custom cookies

so i want to know that in which circumstances we will use following `1. View State 2. session state 3. custom cookies` will any one describe importance and use of each

Comment: Is this, by any chance, homework? :-) Its quite a broad question. Might be better if you explained your scenario - so that people may suggest what could be best used for that specific scenario.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Check below article will describe each option in details

[ASP.NET State Management Overview](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/75x4ha6s.aspx)

**Client-Based State Management Options**

- View State
- Control State
- Hidden Fields
- Cookies
- Query Strings

**Server-Based State Management Options**

- Application State
- Profile Properties
- Session State

Comment: @Nishant -- see the link article of msdn which describe you in detail about server based and client based state management

Comment: Client based means: state is saved in the client's browser (i.e., in a cookie, field, query string), server based means: state is saved on the server. Missing in this list perhaps are Cache, Database, State server?

Answer (score 0):

State management is the process by which you maintain state and page information over multiple requests for the same or different pages.

Types of State Management

There are 2 types State Management:

1. Client – Side State Management
   This stores information on the client's computer by embedding the information into a Web page, a uniform resource locator(url), or a cookie. The techniques available to store the state information at the client end are listed down below:

a. View State – Asp.Net uses View State to track the values in the Controls. You can add custom values to the view state. It is used by the Asp.net page framework to automatically save the values of the page and of each control just prior to rendering to the page. When the page is posted, one of the first tasks performed by page processing is to restore view state.

b. Control State – If you create a custom control that requires view state to work properly, you should use control state to ensure other developers don’t break your control by disabling view state.

c. Hidden fields – Like view state, hidden fields store data in an HTML form without displaying it in the user's browser. The data is available only when the form is processed.

d. Cookies – Cookies store a value in the user's browser that the browser sends with every page request to the same server. Cookies are the best way to store state data that must be available for multiple Web pages on a web site.

e. Query Strings - Query strings store values in the URL that are visible to the user. Use query strings when you want a user to be able to e-mail or instant message state data with a URL.

2. Server – Side State Management

a. Application State - Application State information is available to all pages, regardless of which user requests a page.

b. Session State – Session State information is available to all pages opened by a user during a single visit.

Both application state and session state information is lost when the application restarts. To persist user data between application restarts, you can store it using profile properties.

Advantages

Advantages of Client – Side State Management:

1. Better Scalability: With server-side state management, each client that connects to the Web server consumes memory on the Web server. If a Web site has hundreds or thousands of simultaneous users, the memory consumed by storing state management information can become a limiting factor. Pushing this burden to the clients removes that potential bottleneck.
2. Supports multiple Web servers: With client-side state management, you can distribute incoming requests across multiple Web servers with no changes to your application because the client provides all the information the Web server needs to process the request. With server-side state management, if a client switches servers in the middle of the session, the new server does not necessarily have access to the client’s state information. You can use multiple servers with server-side state management, but you need either intelligent load-balancing (to always forward requests from a client to the same server) or centralized state management (where state is stored in a central database that all Web servers access).

Advantages of Server – Side State Management:

1. Better security: Client-side state management information can be captured (either in transit or while it is stored on the client) or maliciously modified. Therefore, you should never use client-side state management to store confidential information, such as a password, authorization level, or authentication status.
2. Reduced bandwidth: If you store large amounts of state management information, sending that information back and forth to the client can increase bandwidth utilization and page load times, potentially increasing your costs and reducing scalability. The increased bandwidth usage affects mobile clients most of all, because they often have very slow connections. Instead, you should store large amounts of state management data (say, more than 1 KB) on the server

http://www.devdescent.com/2012/05/state-management.html